# Как работает git reset --soft?

Tags: git, git-reset

Сделал пару коммитов в основной ветке. Выполнил команду:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
b8ef55f60786200dfd5c70dd619b45a3d4705ab9 main2
8a7bad0c7ad190811d478d908153de257b79eaf1 main1
```

Далее сбрасываюсь до первого коммита, не меняя файлов

```
$ git reset --soft 8a7bad
```

Делаю коммит и проверяю результат коммитов:

```
$ git commit -m 'main2.1'
$ git log --pretty=oneline
e14e01d7281e4519f20dec0acce6073b95051fcd main2.1
8a7bad0c7ad190811d478d908153de257b79eaf1 main1
```

всё хорошо, но сейчас я могу переключится как на коммит main 2.1 так и на main 2. Причём переключившись например на main 2, я не вижу main 2.1 и наоборот (main 2.1 не видит main 2). Это что такое ? Как будто ветвление но какоето направильное )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git представляет собой дерево коммитов. Где у каждого коммита есть один или несолкько предков. 
`git reset` всего лишь меняет текующий указатель `HEAD` ветки(в Вашем случае `master`, я полагаю). Т.е. он ничего не удаляет, просто Ваш `main2` коммит стал недосягаем из `master` ветки, потому что `master` ветка указывает на `main2.1`, который указывает на `main1`, который ничего не знает о `main2`. Рекомендую почитать книгу по устройству git, чтобы легче было с ним работать.

Comment: я знаю это. я вижу что у меня получился мусор в репозитории.

Comment: если Вы это знаете, то зачем спрашиваете?

Comment: О мусоре и ссылке на коммит которая пропала? нет, этого я не знал.

Comment: Мусор будет очищен, git об это позаботится. Нет смысла о нём волноваться